# How does com_contact caching work when it has a form token?

Tags: component, form, cache, security-token

I've been looking into conservative caching recently and felt I'd got my head around it.  However, when I added it to a site, I was surprised to see that the core component com_content caches forms.  I had assumed that due to form tokens that this would not be a possible thing to do, and so had left any bespoke form modules not using caching.

The cached content definitely includes the old form token, but the form still works.

How is this the case?